# Webpack does not preserve symlinks in project path

Tags: macos, dropbox, symlink

I created a symlink for my "Dropbox (Personal)" folder so I could have an asset path without spaces. If I build my webpack project from a project there, however, it still uses the original path when running and referencing assets. I'm on OSX btw.

**Current behavior**

```
$ pwd
/Users/<me>/<SYMLINK>/<project>

$ webpack
> <project> dev /Users/<me>/<ORIGINAL>/<project>
```

**Desired behavior**

```
$ pwd
/Users/<me>/<SYMLINK>/<project>

$ webpack
> <project> dev /Users/<me>/<SYMLINK>/<project>
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve the above? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Turns out I needed to use a hard link for the Dropbox folder instead of a soft link. The soft link just meant it was basically an alias that always gets resolved to the real path. A hard link means it acts as an actual folder that contains links to the same data as the original. I used the following steps to do it properly:

- Quit Dropbox app
- `$ mv "Dropbox (Personal)" Dropbox`
- `$ ln -s Dropbox "Dropbox (Personal)"`

I can now effectively use the Dropbox directory exactly the same as Dropbox Personal.

Also removing the webpack tag since the issue turned out to be unrelated to webpack.

Comment: An alternative? Maybe let's talk about why you are doing this? :)  Assuming you need to share across computers, can you use an alternate method like a free hosted git repo?

Comment: @olore thanks for the suggestion but I discovered the problem was I'm an idiot and didn't create a proper link in the first place

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to enable symlinks - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-symlinks

```
resolve: {
  /* other stuff */
  symlinks: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response -- in this case, I want it to use the symlink as the path, rather than resolve it to the true path. I tried this option just now with symlinks set to false (and true for good measure), but didn't get any different result.

Comment: @Henry You could also try this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/554#issuecomment-565541421

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to use a hard link for the Dropbox folder instead of a soft link. The soft link just meant it was basically an alias that always gets resolved to the real path. A hard link means it acts as an actual folder that contains links to the same data as the original. I used the following steps to do it properly:

- Quit Dropbox app
- `$ mv "Dropbox (Personal)" Dropbox`
- `$ ln -s Dropbox "Dropbox (Personal)"`

I can now effectively use the *Dropbox* directory exactly the same as *Dropbox Personal*.

Also removing the webpack tag since the issue turned out to be unrelated to webpack.

Comment: I think you want to remove the `-s` in your `ln` command. `-s` makes it a symlink